# Perform processing on string delimited list

Tags: bash

I have three sets of string delimited variables that look like this:

```
listNames="tom~susan~stafano~isabella"
listAges="23~45~34~10"
listNationality="british~american~italian~spanish"
```

I also have a target variable to remove in those lists, i.e.

```
targetName="susan"
```

If target name is "susan", then I want the index of the element to be removed across all of the variables, so it ends up looking like this. Please note that I mean "index" in a position of certain substrings within a larger string, not in the traditional sense where it is associated with arrays:

```
listNames="tom~stafano~isabella"
listAges="23~34~10"
listNationality="british~italian~spanish"
```

How can I implement this in Bash? Especially as I need to retain the variables in string format as above (and not convert them to explicit array structures, as they get passed into another script in the above format).

Comment: What do you mean by "index"? The starting position of a substring in a string? Please also remove the word "array" from the title of your question. Your case does not involve arrays, so the title is misleading.

Comment: So in the example above, susan is in index 1, so everything in "index 1" across all of the variables need to be removed

Comment: I would convert first the strings into arrays, then perform the operations on the arrays, and finally convert them back into strings. Of course, bash is not exactly the best language for this kind of task...

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, I'm struggling with this here. This is why I need some help figuring out how to do it, as the process needs to be embedded in the scope of a larger bash script

Comment: So in your definition, and "index" is a position of certain substrings within a larger string? Please add this kind of information to your question, not in a comment.

Comment: There are **three** subtasks: Creating the array, manipulating it, and turning it into a string again. Since these are pretty different tasks, please make separate questions out of them, and also show your own effort in solving them.

Comment: _embedded in the scope of a larger bash script_  You can "embed" any language, including Perl or Ruby. Why not writing a small Perl or awk program and using it from your bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example that splits your strings into arrays, removes matching elements, and then recreates the strings:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

listNames="tom~susan~stafano~isabella"
listAges="23~45~34~10"
listNationality="british~american~italian~spanish"
targetName=susan

# Use tilde instead of whitespace as field delimiter
IFS="~"

# Split into arrays
read -r -a aNames <<<"$listNames"
read -r -a aAges <<<"$listAges"
read -r -a aNationality <<<"$listNationality"

# Look for susan and delete the corresponding elements
nNames=${#aNames[@]}
for (( i = 0; i < nNames; i++)); do
    if [[ ${aNames[i]} == "$targetName" ]]; then
        unset "aNames[i]"
        unset "aAges[i]"
        unset "aNationality[i]"
    fi
done

# Turn back into strings;
# ${foo[*]} puts the value of IFS between elements of foo
listNames=${aNames[*]}
listAges=${aAges[*]}
listNationality=${aNationality[*]}

# Output them for example's sake
declare -p listNames listAges listNationality
```

Comment: As per OP, _If target name is "susan", then I want the index of the element to be removed across all of the variables_, so i believe it's required to loop over all the variables(except `targetName`) just like : `nNames`?

Comment: @A.K Nope, only needs one loop. Note the three `unset`s.

Comment: Nice answer/solution, `unset` is really good for this. upvoted!

Comment: You could also combine them into one `unset "aNames[i]" "aAges[i]" "aNationality[i]"` and save a few lines but I wanted that part to stand out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without the `unset` which was used by *@Shawn*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

listNames="tom~susan~stafano~isabella"
listAges="23~45~34~10"
listNationality="british~american~italian~spanish"
targetName="stafano"
to_loop=0

while IFS='~' read -ra line; do
  if ((!to_loop)); then
    for i in "${!line[@]}"; do
      [[ ${line[i]} == "$targetName" ]] &&
      index=$i && break
    done
  fi
  to_loop=1
  line=("${line[*]/"${line[index]}"}")
  line=("${line[*]// /\~}")
  line=("${line[*]/~~/\~}")
  line=("${line[*]%\~}")
  values+=("${line[*]#\~}")
done < <(
  printf '%s\n' "$listNames" "$listAges" "$listNationality"
)

var_names=( listNames listAges listNationality)

##: Just to show the OLD values of the variables not needed in the script
declare -p listNames listAges listNationality; printf '\n'

##: loop through the variable names and assign the new values.
for j in "${!var_names[@]}"; do
  printf -v new_values '%s=%s' "${var_names[j]}" "${values[j]}"
  declare "$new_values"
done

##: Just to show the NEW values of the variables not needed in the script
declare -p listNames listAges listNationality
```

---

Output

```
declare -- listNames="tom~susan~stafano~isabella"
declare -- listAges="23~45~34~10"
declare -- listNationality="british~american~italian~spanish"

declare -- listNames="tom~stafano~isabella"
declare -- listAges="23~34~10"
declare -- listNationality="british~italian~spanish"
```

---

Using `unset` this is how I would do it. (which @Shawn used with his answer)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

listNames="tom~susan~stafano~isabella"
listAges="23~45~34~10"
listNationality="british~american~italian~spanish"
targetName="stafano"
to_loop=0

while IFS='~' read -ra line; do
  if ((!to_loop)); then
    for i in "${!line[@]}"; do
      [[ ${line[i]} == "$targetName" ]] &&
      index=$i && break
    done
  fi
  to_loop=1
  unset 'line[index]'
  values+=("${line[*]}")
done < <(
  printf '%s\n' "$listNames" "$listAges" "$listNationality"
)

var_names=( listNames listAges listNationality )

##: Just to show the OLD values of the variables not needed in the script
declare -p listNames listAges listNationality ; printf '\n'

##: loop through the variable names and assign the new values.
for j in "${!var_names[@]}"; do
  printf -v new_values '%s=%s' "${var_names[j]}" "${values[j]// /\~}"
  declare "$new_values"
done

##: Just to show the NEW values of the variables not needed in the script
declare -p listNames listAges listNationality
```